# Making an image pop out of div

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with 2 divs ,
div1 and div2 occupying 50% of the screens vertically.

I have an image present in div2. I have a button, and on click of the button, I need the image to be occupied 100% of the screen coming out of all the divs and on click of the second button go back to the original position in div2.

Is it possible?

Comment: could you please show us what you have done..

Comment: everything is possible...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b3rzvzgm/1/

Comment: just toggle the css for that image and give it a position static/absolute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm9f4zj3/2/)

In the fiddle I set the position of the image to absolute and sets it height and  width to 100% on click of the `fullscreen` button.

**HTML**

```
<div class="testDiv div1"></div>
<div class="testDiv div2">
    <img id="myImg" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/grass_PNG4930.png" />
    <button onclick="fullscreen();">Fullscreen</button>
    <button onclick="closefs();">Close</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function fullscreen() {
    var elt=document.getElementById('myImg');
    elt.style.position = 'absolute';
    elt.style.height = "100%";
    elt.style.width = "100%";
    elt.style.top = "0";
    elt.style.bottom = "0";
    elt.style.left = "0";
    elt.style.right = "0";
}

function closefs() {
    var elt=document.getElementById('myImg');
    elt.style.position = 'static';
    elt.style.height = "50px";
    elt.style.width = "50px";

}
```

Comment: I was the downvoter. I'm impressed. You managed to figure out the reason and make the necessary edits after asking why. I've changed the vote.

Comment: Oh great.. :D.. I was actually editing the post while you downvoted.. ;) @BoltClock

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's possible. Here, you can do it this way. 
Refer below given code snippet.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_poss = 0;
function change(){
    if(current_poss==0){
        $('#div1').css('width','0%');
        $('#div2').css('width','100%');
        $('#div2 img').css('width', '100%');
        current_poss = 1;
    }
    else{
        $('#div1').css('width','50%');
        $('#div2').css('width','50%');
        $('#div2 img').css('width', '100%');
        current_poss = 0;
    }
}
</script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1" style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="float:left;width:50%;height:100%;">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Moon.jpg" height="100%" wdith="100%">
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="change();">Click here</button>
```

Comment: @Lal check this now. If you are developer than you might notice error getting in console for change() function. I had just wrote code snippet to give him brief idea about logic.

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach could be just jquery to add a class to your image container so lately you can modifie your container without adding anything to the script (my favourite way):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.show').click(function () {
                $('.right').addClass("full"); 
            });
            $('.hide').click(function () {
                $('.right').removeClass("full"); 
            });
        });
```

and with these simple css:

```
body, html {height:100%; margin:0;}
.left {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
.right {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Freshwater_spring_next_to_Mono_Lake-1000px.jpeg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
.show {position:absolute; left:20px; top:20%;z-index:10;}
.hide {position:absolute; left:20px; top:30%; z-index:10;}

.full {position:absolute; width:100%; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; margin:auto;}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/4gjxyu8n/)**